# GTK-Builder memory leaks when load a file created with Glade

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk, builder, glade

I would first apologize to all my English is not good . When I boot my GTK widgets with gtk_builder_add_from_files ( builder , " interface.xml " & err) I have no errors but I have these memory leaks that appear :

For two days I search a solution but in vain. Or someone would have an idea has already been confronted with the problem ?

```
Leak: 0x7fa3c9d49dd0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000     length: 3  "hfs"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9e25a20  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000     length: 7  "<ctrl>v"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e28280  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>F"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e569f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e5d5f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>x"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e5f910  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e6e930  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e76400  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
   Leak: 0x7fa3c9e8c3f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ea84c0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ea9df0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eaadf0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>F"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eaf990  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eaf9a0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eaf9f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb0030  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>v"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb1540  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>c"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb21f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>f"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb2460  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb25f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb2df0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb49f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb75f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>v"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb7bf0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>f"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9eb83f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ec11f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ec25f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ec31f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>c"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ec3df0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>c"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ecab90  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>c"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ecd5f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 14  "<shift><ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9ecd9f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>a"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9edc9f0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 7  "<ctrl>x"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9f07fb0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 12  "/dev/disk0s2"
Leak: 0x7fa3c9f9c500  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x109274000  length: 10  "(646, 267)"
```

I get this logs with "leaks" program on mac os X El Capitan and i can't use valgrind. He crash when he tried to launch the program. :(

Thank you for your time and good day .

Comment: Are you sure these are _true_ leaks, and not just memory that will remain allocated for the lifetime of the application? It is more efficient for an application to not bother explicitly free-ing memory that it needs for its entire lifetime - when it exits, the OS will deallocate everything anyway.  Look in the Gtk+ reference manual; it may have an optional debugging mode in which it explicitly frees everything to make leak checkers happy.

Answer (score 0):

Is your .gtkbuilder XML is correct in the first place? It is loaded as is, without proper pre-checks or error handling and any error may and will lead to a leak or crash. Consider checking the return code of `gtk_builder_add_from_file()`. If it is zero (which means error) then you have a problem.

Also make sure that you do not lose pointers to your GtkBuilder. If you want to remove it you have to do `g_object_unref()`.

Other than that you should not worry about how GtkBuilder manages memory.

Comment: Hello, I  already check on my code the return code of gtk_builder_add_from_file() and I used g_object_unref() after generate my widgets. Maybe XML generate with Glade is incorrect... I read on GNOME GTK+3 documentation than an incorrect file can cause memory leak.  Thank you for your response and your time.